# Minimum and maximum using user input as data script for assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I actually started a course. Very easy course even though I did not have Python experience before (The course is called "..... for everyone")

I'm on the last assignment before finishing the course and I have to create a script to find the minimum and maximum number of a list of 5 different inputs `(7, 2, bob, 10, 4)` which one is not valid and my script should output a message of "Invalid Input".

This is the base code that they give you to start.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
num = input("Enter a number: ")
if num == "done" : break
print(num)`enter code here`

print("Maximum", largest)
```

---

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "Done" :
        break
    #print(num)
    try:
        fnum = float(num)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
#for largest in fnum : possible
if largest is None :
    largest = fnum
elif fnum > largest :
    largest = fnum
#for smallest in fnum : possible
if smallest is None :
    smallest = fnum
elif fnum < smallest :
    smallest = fnum


print('Maximum is', largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

---

All the code work perfect when I type the input...
But then when I type "Done" which finishes the script. It always gives me the last Input I typed.
I saw different scripts that work for the same purpose, but I don't want to copy any script of other person. I'm doing this course to learn, and I would like if someone could help me pointing the mistake or giving me some recommendations.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Of course you can use indentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting.

Comment: "the forum would not let me" ... please repeat the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), especially the references for how to format your post.  Don't blame it on "the forum" (which this is not).

Comment: Sorry my bad. I did not mean to blame the forum. As I said I'm new and I do not know how to use it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.. This is what I was supposed to do:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "Done" :
        break
    #print(num)
    try:
        fnum = float(num)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
#for largest in fnum : possible
    if largest is None :
        largest = fnum
    elif fnum > largest :
        largest = fnum
    #for smallest in fnum : possible
    if smallest is None :
        smallest = fnum
    elif fnum < smallest :
        smallest = fnum
def done(largest,smallest):
    print ("Maximum is", int(largest))
    print ("Minimum is", int(smallest))

done(largest,smallest)
```

Thank you @DSPR for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not bad for a 6 days coder :-)

Just a little tip : when you compute the min or max of a series of values, you can start with the opposite limit. I mean if you're looking for the min, you can start with your variable set to the max. Unlike other languages, Python doesn't fix the integer limits, but you can fix them yourself. For instance this form :

```
smallest = None
for value in values:
  if smallest is None or smallest value < smallest:
    smallest = value
return smallest
```

Could be little bit more compact expressed like this :

```
smallest = 1000000 # depending on your needs (in C we would write INT_MAX for instance)
for value in values:
    if value < smallest: smallest = value
return smallest
```

Note that you never return the initial value anyway.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much. But I need to use the value None as requirement of the assignment... So I still really confused of how to do it.